# Не увеличивает переменную в JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть простой код: http://jsbin.com/yulaturibe/edit?html,js,console,output

JS

```
// Функция отрисовки
function Draw(val1, val2) {
    var Header = '<div id="left">'+val1+'</div><div id="right">'+val2+'</div>';
    return Header;
}

var val1 = 1;
var val2 = 5;

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=Draw(val1, val2);

// Функция добавления
left.onclick = function() {
    console.log(val1);
    val1++;
    return val1;
};
```

HTML из 1 строки:

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

Вопроса 2:

1. Почему обновлённое значение val1 не отображается на странице, но в консоли увеличивается? И как сделать так что бы увеличивалось на странице?
2. Как в данном случае переписать скрипт что бы избавится от глобальных переменных val1 и val2?

Comment: _Почему обновлённое значение val1 не отображается на странице_ -
 потому что ты вызвал `Draw` только **один** раз. Код с разметкой никак не связан, разметка **всегда** меняется только вручную.

Comment: @Grundy точно, поменял что б при клике опять Draw вызывалась, но теперь какой-то не понятный косяк, увеличивается только 1 раз, консоль ошибок не пишет http://jsbin.com/zuzokegige/edit?html,js,output

Comment: не вижу у тебя определение переменной left

Comment: @Grundy ок, почему же тогда увеличивается в первый раз?

Comment: а, все, нашел твой left :-D в нем как раз все и проблема :-) элемент ты добавляешь на страницу много раз, а обработчик нажатия по нему только один раз. вот он один раз и работает. При этом старый элемент стирается, а новому ты обработчик не добавляешь

Comment: @Grundy вроде понял но не очень. Обработчик нажатия один раз. Это left.onclick? В моём понятии. Отрисовали Draw слушаем нажатие. Нажали, меняем глобальную val1 и с ней новой отправляем данные на отрисовку снова в Draw - она заново всё отрисовывает, случаем опять нажатие и так по кругу

Comment: Ага, вот только при _отрисовке_ через innerHTML - **все** что было внутри элемента удаляется и создается новое. И у этих новых элементов, ты не устанавливаешь никаких обработчиком

Comment: @Grundy ну да, я всё удалил и заново всё отрисовал и у внось отрисованного блока так же есть id=left а старый обработчик left.onclick так же вроде как должен ловить вновь отрисованные блоки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63142/discussion-between-grundy-and-fosh4455).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не изменяется потому что вы не изменяете innerHTML по клику.
2. Вот так, например.

   ```js
   function draw() {
     var val1 = 1;
     var val2 = 5;
     var Header = '<div id="left">' + val1 + '</div><div id="right">' + val2 + '</div>';
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Header;
     document.getElementById('left').onclick = function() {
       val1++;
       var Header = '<div id="left">' + val1 + '</div><div id="right">' + val2 + '</div>';
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Header;
       console.log(val1);
       return val1;
     };
   }

   draw();
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="left">
     <div id="text"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Отработка только по нажатию на left и меньший по объему код. На left каждый раз надо заново вешать onclick потому что мы перезаписываем left и onclick пропадает

```js
function draw() {
  var val1 = 1;
  var val2 = 5;
  var text = document.getElementById('text');

  text.innerHTML = '<div id="left">' + val1 + '</div><div id="right">' + val2 + '</div>';
  document.getElementById('left').onclick = leftPlusNum;

  function leftPlusNum() {
    val1++;
    text.innerHTML = '<div id="left">' + val1 + '</div><div id="right">' + val2 + '</div>';
    document.getElementById('left').onclick = leftPlusNum;
  };
}

draw();
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Вёрстку менять нельзя, должен остатья только 1 финальный блок, в который и происходит весь вывод. Если у вас убрать div с id=left то так же будет увеличиться 1 раз до 2 и останавливаться

Comment: @fosh4455 А что тогда обозначает переменная left в вашем коде?

Comment: Это айдишник id=left, но генерируется он внутри JS в Draw()

Comment: @fosh4455 Такой код работает именно по нажатию на блок с id="left"